# The ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID happens just in Chrome and Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, .net, angular, https, ssl-certificate

The project that I'm working on is a single page application. Frontend is `Angular 15` and backend is `.NET 7`.

When I run the project from `Firefox` browser, there is no problem but when I run it from `Chrome` or `Microsoft Edge`, I get this error:

> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

How can I solve this error?

[image: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID]

**--------- Updated ----------**

I upgraded the .NET SDK to 7.0.2 and executed the following procedures:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean

dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

(I run the command prompt as admin when I did this.)

And now, the project works nicely on Chrome but not on Microsoft Edge!

*(The connection is not secure but the Certificate is valid)*

In addition, when I submit the order through Stripe, I get an error.

> ([ERROR] Failed to POST: Post
> "https://localhost:6001/api/payments/webhook": x509: certificate
> signed by unknown authority)

[image: chrome Not secure]

[image: stripe error]